# Error while passing a tuple to a generic method

Tags: scala, generics

Here is a function to memoize /cache intermediate result :

```
 def memoize[I, O](f: I => O) = new scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[I, O]() {
   override def apply(key: I): O = getOrElseUpdate(key, f(key))    
 }
```

This works fine for code like below,

```
val double: Int=>Int = memoize {
    _*2
}
```

However, when I try to use tuple as input parameter(I) it shows compile time error,

```
val isGivenNumIsHead:(List[Int], Int) => Boolean = memoize {
  case (Nil, _) => false
  case (a:: as, n) => a == n
}
```

Compile time error is :

***Expression of type mutable.HashMap[Nothing, Boolean] {def apply(key: Nothing): Boolean} doesn't conform to expected type (List[Int], Int) => Boolean***

Is this something related to erasure.

How do i fix it ?

Comment: I'm confused.  `memoize` returns a `HashMap[O, I]`, yet you want to return a function of type: `(List[Int], Int]) => Boolean`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you want to use the tuple as the key in the HashMap. With that in mind, here is the explanation.

The actual return type of `memoize` is `scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[_,_]` . That is being assigned to `double` which is of type `Int => Int` or `Function1[Int,Int]` ( a function that takes an integer and gives an interger). The compiler doesnt throw an error because `mutable.HashMap` extends `scala.collection.mutable.MapLike` which in turn extends `scala.collection.MapLike` which in turn extends `scala.PartialFunction[A, B]` which in turn extends `scala.Function1[A, B]`.  Hence there is no compilation error.

On the other hand, the syntax for functions taking one parameter and returning one value is `val functionName : A => B = a => {return b}` or can be written as `val function : (A) => B = a => {return b}` or `val function: (A => B) = a => {return b}`. You have used the second method. In that case, the value of A should be of single type. You have used `List[Int],Int` which is not a single type. Note that I intentionally removed the brackets. So in order to make that as a single type and to pass it as a tuple, you have to use one more set of brackets. The correct syntax would be

```
val isGivenNumIsHead:((List[Int], Int)) => Boolean = memoize {
  case (Nil, _) => false
  case (a:: as, n) => a == n
}
```

Note the usage of additional brackets to make it a tuple.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Thanks for the detailed and nice explanation !